# Python: How to get multiple lines in file?

Tags: python, file

How can I get the value with multiple lines from a file?
For example. I have a file containing this:

```
Anna#18#Goodmorning! 
How are you?
```

What should I do to get this output?

```
Goodmorning!
How are you?
```

I tried using .splitlines and splitting "#" but it doesn't seem to work.
This what i have so far.

```
newmsg=""
fob = open( "sample.txt" , "r" )
lines = fob.readlines()
for line in lines:
    msg= line.splitlines()
    newmsg += str(msg)
print newmsg
fob.close()
```

This is what it shows:

```
['Anna#18#Goodmorning!']['How are you?']
```

What I need is this:

```
Goodmorning!
How are you?
```

Comment: *but it doesn't seem to work*: how about you share your code and show us the output you do get. Then we can help you fix the problems with that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you please post your code?  It's hard to tell why it's not working without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MartijnPieters posted my code. That is what i have so far..

Comment: @eshi: so what output do you get for that? If there is an exception include the full traceback. What output did you expect instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i posted the output and my desired output. Sorry if my post's not complete. Any tips on how can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With for loop you can iterate through lines and then you can split every line by #. With `" ".join(msg)` you can join elements of array into string, seperated by space.

```
newmsg=""
fob = open( "sample.txt" , "r" )
for line in fob:
    msg = line.split("#")
    msg = msg[-1:]
    newmsg += " ".join(msg)
print (newmsg)
fob.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting "#" is what you want, but you have to do it line by line. Since an open file is already an iterator, I've used it directly in the for loop. And since I've already got a line in the loop I don't try to `splitlines` again.

```
newmsg=""
with open( "sample.txt" , "r" ) as fob:
    for line in fob:
        msg= line.split('#')[-1]
        newmsg += msg
print newmsg
```